# Assign OptionMenu Variable in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, optionmenu

I am working on a menu system that allows user to select date and location to access a specific file.  I know it will be a lot of hard coding for each specific file.  I want to use an OptionMenu system.  I am getting values printed, but how can i define these values and pass them through a function to open that specific file.  I am thinking a long if else statement. (IE if Monday && a then pass this call function).

Here is my code

```
#mainmenu
class MyOptionMenu(OptionMenu):
 def __init__(self, master, status, *options):
    self.var = StringVar(master)
    self.var.set(status)
    OptionMenu.__init__(self, master, self.var, *options)
    self.config(font=('calibri',(20)),bg='white',width=20)
    self['menu'].config(font=('calibri',(10)),bg='white')

root = Tk()
#attemtping to assign numerical values
Monday = 1
Tuesday = 2
Wednesday = 3
Thursday = 4
Friday = 5
mymenu1 = MyOptionMenu(root, 'Select day', 'Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday')
mymenu2 = MyOptionMenu(root, 'Select Location', 'd','e','f')
#menus come up fine and values correctly printed
def ok():
print "value is", (mymenu1.var).get(), (mymenu2.var).get()
button = Button(root, text="OK", command=ok)
button.pack()
mymenu1.pack()
mymenu2.pack()
(mymenu1.var).get()
(mymenu2.var).get()
#assign variable x to return values
x = (mymenu1.var).get()
if x <2:
    print 'Negative changed to zero'
elif x == 0:
    print 'Zero'
elif x == 1:
    print 'Single'
else:
    print 'More'

root.mainloop()
```

I am getting this as an output
"More"/
"value is Monday e", which shows I am able to access the correct outcome, but I am lost on implementing that variable (Tuesday) in the next step.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to find the right file using the input day and letter. How to do this depends on the files locations and names. Are all files in the same folder? If not what are the folders called (and is this fixed or can you change it however you want)? What are the files called (and again can you change this or not)? All these different situation would probably have different solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JustForFun, your question is a little tangled and a bit hard to contemplate, but I think i understand what you want.
Firstly you have put the last part at the wrong place (from `#assign variable x to return values`), this will be run through at the start, but not after the `ok` button is clicked, so `x` will always equal `'Select day'` (thus why you get `more` printed when you run it), you should put this inside a function to be called in `ok()`, or in `ok()` itself:

```
def ok():
    print "value is", (mymenu1.var).get(), (mymenu2.var).get()
    x = (mymenu1.var).get()
    if x <2:
        print 'Negative changed to zero'
    elif x == 0:
        print 'Zero'
    elif x == 1:
        print 'Single'
    else:
        print 'More'
```

This will get the value for x and test it when `ok` is clicked, and it can lead to more actions like using the results gained to open a file etc. BUT, you have (I think) just rushed the last part with the `if/elif` etc statements as the first `if...:` will pick up items below 2 (<), so the next two `elif` statements aren't going to evaluate as true, do you intend to have (>) in the first statement?
Also you probably need to include a variable for the second optionmenu in the `if/elif` statements:

```
if x > 2 and y == ...:
    # open specific file? etc...
```